# Running Spark App: Persist Metastore

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I work on a Spark 2.1 application that also uses SparkSQL and saves data with `dataframe.write.saveAsTable(tbl)`. My understanding is that an in-memory Derby DB is used for the Hive metastore (right?). This means that a table that I create in the first execution is not available in any subsequent executions. In many cases that might be the intended behaviour - but I would like to persist the metastore across executions (since this is also the behavior I have in my production system).

So, a simple question: How can I change the configuration to persist the metastore on disc?

One remark: I am not starting the Spark job with spark-shell or spark-submit, but as a standalone Scala application.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is already persisted on disk. As long as both sessions use the same working directory or specific metastore configuration, the permanent table will be persisted between sessions.

Comment: This answer looks unfinished and is at high risk for flagging.  I would recommend that you expand it somewhat, perhaps with some quotes from some refrences / websites that would be pertinent and help prove your answer.  At very least, don't end an answer with a comma.  :)

Comment: I can confirm the answer - but I want to mention that you need to include .enableHiveSupport() when creating the Spark Session. Only then the Metastore is persisted.